# unable to merge array in key value format

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am trying to merge array in key-value format but unfortunately, I couldn't get the result what I need. by the print following array, I get the following result.

```
 $material = array_merge($dataArrMaterial,$dataTotalMaterialQty);
_print($material);

Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1041
        [material_qty] => 30
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1046
        [material_qty] => 10
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [material_qty_req] => 90
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [material_qty_req] => 30
    )
)
```

but i want the result like this

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1041
        [material_qty] => 30
        [material_qty_req] => 90

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [material_name] => 1046
        [material_qty] => 10
        [material_qty_req] => 30
    )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your `$dataArrMaterial,$dataTotalMaterialQty` array in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop the first array and then use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge multidimensional array.

```
$result= [];
foreach($dataArrMaterial as $key => $value){
    $result[$key] = array_merge($dataArrMaterial[$key], $dataTotalMaterialQty[$key]);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: without knowing array structure how to loop?

Comment: He mentions both the array in question @BhargavChudasama

Comment: he define the output of merge array not actual array

Comment: From the defined output you can take an assumption that he/she is looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `foreach()` method of php.

```
foreach($dataArrMaterial as $key=> $value){
    $data[] = array(
        'material_name'=> $value['material_name'],
        'material_qty'=> $value['material_qty'],
        'material_qty_req'=> $dataTotalMaterialQty[$key]['material_qty_req'],

    );
}
```

Comment: without knowing array structure how to loop?

Comment: Read the question he has mentioned the array. If you don't know the structure then you have to first print the array to check the structure then make a loop accordingly.

Comment: how i can `print` the array i have not ant data about array